# How can I resolve "A clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor within the allocated time interval."?

Tags: bsod

I've been troubled by my laptop problem lately. It always blue screen error every time I use it.

Every time it becomes blue screen it shows:

> A clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor within the allocated time interval.

I don't understand what it means, and I even bought a new HDD and RAM, I also haven't install new programs but the blue screen always appears. Is there anyone who has same problem with me and knows how to solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried any of the myriads of solutions that come up when you put that error message into Google? If so, which ones? With what outcome? Why did you buy a new HDD to try to solve **that** error?

Answer (score 0):

This error is commonly associated with overclocking your processor. There have also been anecdotes saying that adjusting power management settings or updating device drivers have worked (sound or video).

A few microsoft forums has suggesting reseting your BIOS settings back to factory default.

Due to the nature of the fault it is not impossible that it is caused by a faulty processor, but unlikely.

It is very unlikely to be caused by either your HDD or system memory. It may be easier to seek assistance from the manufacturer if the laptop is still under maintenance or warranty.